# LightSwitch DatePicker Default Value

Tags: datepicker, default, visual-studio-lightswitch

In LightSwitch, my experience has been that a date picker will show the most recent date viewed for a particular field when a null date is viewed.

For instance:
1  I view a Contract Offer Date that is set to '5/1/2012' on one detail page of a List and Details screen. 
2. Then I go to another page where the Contract Offer Date is null
3. If I bring up the datepicker, it will start out with '5/1/2012' selected.

Is there any way to change this behavior so if the date is null the datepicker will open with the current date selected?

Thanks for your help.